# Main Webmasters chat room is frozen (again) - can this be unfrozen?

Tags: support, chat

**UPDATE 30-June-2021** *(bump)* The chat room is frozen again! In fact, it only remained "unfrozen" (by Dan) last time for 2 days before it was automatically frozen again! It has been frozen ever since - 42 days so far.

It seems that if no-one posts a "chat" message in the first 2 days after the room is "unfrozen", it gets automatically frozen again! So, next time the room is unfrozen, post a chat message at the same time, and perhaps post back here as well.

---

**UPDATE 11-May-2021** - It appears to have been frozen again (4 days ago).

---

I just noticed that the [main Webmasters chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters) is frozen (for being inactive for a period of time) - can this be unfrozen?

[image: Webmasters chat room is frozen]

It's good to have a global Webmasters chat room:

- I like to throw down the odd chat message once in a while.
- A good place to post "newsy" Webmasters stuff.
- (New) Users have a place to discuss "whatever" before posting on the main site.

Comment: I just noticed the edit here and unfroze the chat room again. Unfortunately it will periodically get frozen if there isn't any chat comments - hope it gets used more often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be re-opened.  I unfroze it.

Comment: And then it froze again!

Comment: Unfrozen again.

Comment: I'd use it if yall wanted to make it a thing